# PHP sample project with wamp

Tags: php, netbeans, wamp

I installed wamp stack and then installed netbeans ide. The port number for apache is 100.
Created one PHP project at

`C:\Users\aaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject2`

and project URL http://localhost:100/PhpProject2/

When I click on run, I see the message "http://localhost:100/PhpProject2/index.php URL not found on the server".

What else I need to do to connect http://localhost:100/PhpProject2/index.php to `C:\Users\aaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject2`?

Please help.

Comment: Whats the document root of `localhost:1000` or the local path of `localhost:1000/PhpProject2`? Did you restart your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to `http://localhost:100/`, what do you see? What is your web root?  The folder needs to be in your web root, and I would be surprised if it is `C:\Users\aaa\Documents\`

I did a Google search for "wamp stack" and found a product by Bitnami... if this is the one you are using, the default web root is `C:\Program Files\BitNami WAMP Stack\apache2\htdocs\`.  If that is indeed the case, then you'd need to move the `NetBeansProjects` folder to there. (source: http://bitnami.org/files/stacks/wampstack/5.3.6-0/wampstack.pdf page 7)

Comment: Thanks you. It was a breeze with the document. My bad, i did not put enough time on reading this pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure Apache's webroot to be `C:\Users\aaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects` (search for `DocumentRoot` in the file `httpd.conf`).

**Or** you can move/copy your files to the existing webroot, which may be something like `c:\wwwroot`.

Apache doesn't just magically know where you put your website files, and setting the URL inside NetBeans doesn't actually configure the webserver (I think it's just so that auto-generated links are right).

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [aliasing](http://www.thewebhostinghero.com/tutorials/apache-alias.html). That will let you more or less assign directories in the url path to arbitrary directories on your file system.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your files to your root folder of the Apache installation (htdocs). You should refer to your WAMP installation for where that is located. Personally, I like to use XXAMP for installation.

Netbeans is just an IDE, it doesn't serve the files.

Comment: I tried installing xxamp but everytime got error that port 80 is already used, could not install apache. Stopped IIS service still same error so left it there. Will install Xdebug seperately. Thanks.